# Wifi stops randomly

Tags: wireless, dell, ubuntu-studio

I'm running Ubuntu Studio 18.10 on a Dell Latitude. After a seemingly random amount of time (but at least 20 minutes... sometimes over an hour), my wifi stops, and is no longer present on the Network Manager panel. I need to reboot my PC to get it up again.

I'm getting wifi firmware errors (but, the wifi is working regardless - but I don't know for how long):

```
mike@hurricane:~$ dmesg | grep wifi
[   14.171159] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   14.171764] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.224862] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
[   14.738890] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
[   15.212507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   15.212509] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   15.212511] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   15.212514] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN, REV=0x74
[   17.521848] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   33.160746] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
[   33.403828] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x3-0x1
```

Info re. my computer:

```
mike@hurricane:~$ inxi
CPU: Dual Core Intel Core i5-2520M (-MT MCP-) 
speed/min/max: 3016/800/3200 MHz Kernel: 4.18.0-13-lowlatency x86_64 Up: 21m 
Mem: 1067.9/7853.4 MiB (13.6%) Storage: 298.09 GiB (61.4% used) Procs: 216 
Shell: bash 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.24 

mike@hurricane:~$ inxi -M
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude E6420 v: 01 
  serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0K0DNP v: A02 serial: <root required> BIOS: Dell v: A08 
  date: 10/18/2011 

mike@hurricane:~$ uname -a
Linux hurricane 4.18.0-13-lowlatency #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 5 12:12:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

...and the networking hardware:

```
mike@hurricane:~$ inxi -n
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e 
  IF: eno1 state: down mac: d4:be:d9:19:89:0f 
  Device-2: Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 24:77:03:39:c1:04 
  IF-ID-1: wwp0s29u1u6i6 state: down mac: 02:80:37:ec:02:00 

mike@hurricane:~$ lspci -v | grep -iE -5 'wifi'
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at e2d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

0a:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Dell OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at e2c20000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
```

I *assume* that these firmware errors are part of the problem - but I really don't know.

I would appreciate any possible assistance. I have tried several Linux distros on this laptop (including Opensuse Leap, MX-17.1, and Netrunner), but have never come across this before. I have reinstalled Ubuntu Studio (both 18.04 and 18.10) but that makes no difference.

Thank you.

Comment: I have just tried the following:

- edit the file: /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

- change the value wifi.powersave = 3 to wifi.powersave = 2

Then reboot and do this: 

echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi11n.conf

This, I am told, will disable the power saving on the wifi modem. I'll give Netflix a try tonight and see how well that works!

Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/slow-wifi-on-intel-centrino-ultimate-n-6300-a-4175599455/

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found a solution:

edit the file: **/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf** 
- change the value **wifi.powersave = 3** to **wifi.powersave = 2** 
- Then reboot and do this:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi11n.conf
```

This will stop the wifi's "powersave" feature. I have tested this by going on an extended Netflix binge, and haven't had any more problems.